# Horrible mistake, Deleting instead of ending workflow

Tags: workflow, restore

Instead of ending the workflow, I deleted the data entry in the list by deleting the employee(  the record was created by form)!
 Can I restore that record? The form collected information from the submitter and several approvers approved the process( Employee separation). I don't know why I deleted the employee instead of simply ending the workflow!!!
Can I restore it? Version control wasn't set either!

Comment: You can get back your deleted data from recycle bin or from secondary recycle bin from site settings.

Answer (score 4):

From what i understand you deleted an item from list and you want to restore it back. To do so you need to navigate to **Site Settings** from top ribbon (you will see this option only if you have certain permissions) on site settings page find **Recycle bin** search for your item in there and just restore it back.

[image]

**NOTE:** If item is/was deleted from here you can check the **Second stage recycle bin**. if you don't find it in second stage as well then there is now way to restore it back.

Comment: I cannot believe I didn't say Thank you. :(     Thank you very much Akshay and Ronak!